# Data Issue While Printing

Tags: css, printing

My site contain a lot of data like 150 records on page, when I press ctrl+p then it will show the first page only, like only the visible part of the page but I want full [ 150] records.

This is what I tried So far:

```
    <style>


   @@media print
{   
    html, body {
  height:100%; 
  margin: 0 !important; 
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow: auto;
 } 
    #header, #menuheader
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    #prctrow
        {
        text-align:center !important;
    }
}

</style>
```

This css remove the scrollbar from print preview but data is still not showing.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps to possibly fix this as it's a bit difficult to see the complete issue with only your CSS.

1. Make sure your actual CSS is using one "@" symbol for "@media print {"
2. "display: inline-block" might need to be set to "display: block;"
3. Anything floated may have to be cleared and set to not float
4. Things positioned absolute or fixed should be set to static
5. Add something at the bottom of the page to test if everything is blank or just the table on the second page